# How do I disable caching completely in cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

What is the best practice to disable caching in local development enviroments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [\Cake\Cache\Cache::disable()](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/caching.html#globally-enable-or-disable-cache) in your `bootstrap.php`. I'm unaware of this being cited as 'best practise', however.

Comment: The default config using 1 or even 0 seconds for cache lifetime is simple enough, isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 4 you can do the following

in `src/Application.php`

```
use Cake\Cache\Cache;
...
    public function bootstrap(): void
    {
        parent::bootstrap();

        if (Configure::read('debug')) {
            Cache::disable();
    }
```

to disable cache completely

Also you can selectively disable only database metadata cache replacing `Cache::disable();` to

```
            $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
            $connection->cacheMetadata(false);
```

Instead of `default` you can select your configured datasources
Do not forget to `use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;`

And then you just need to enable debugging either in `app_local.php` using `'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)` or in `.env` setting `DEBUG=true` (or APP_DEBUG, look carefully in your config) if you are using dotenv. So you will not have uncommitted changes in your local files.